# I want to Check if the values present on a certain column from sheet1 are also present on sheet2 using Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I started my Python journey a few weeks ago. My main goal is to be able to automatise some aspects of my daily work routine, and in the future to dive more on Data Science. For now I'm trying to make a script that will check if the values present on a certain column from sheet1 are also present on sheet2. I managed to get here:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)

df = pd.ExcelFile('C:\\Users\\Andre\\Desktop\\Scraps\\abacus.xlsx')
sheet1 = pd.read_excel(df, 'Sheet1')
sheet2 = pd.read_excel(df, 'Sheet2')

print(type(df))
print(sheet1)
print(sheet2)

df['Ref'] = df.lookup(df.index, df[sheet2['Ref']])
```

I know that my last line is incorrect, but it also states that 'ExcelFile' object has no attribute 'lookup', so I'm not managing to find a path to explore. Someone can point me a direction?

Comment: `df` is not a pandas `DataFrame` in this instance, it is an `ExcelFile` object. You need to have a `DataFrame` to do the `DataFrame.lookup()` function. What does `print(df)` and `print(df['Ref'])` return?

Comment: You are right. I can see that print(df) returns just <pandas.io.excel._base.ExcelFile object at 0x0361DFB0> and print(df['Ref']) returns error. 

I'm probably going to fast for my current knowledge and ended up mixing things not compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your code:

```
df = pd.ExcelFile('C:\\Users\\Andre\\Desktop\\Scraps\\abacus.xlsx')
sheet1 = pd.read_excel(df, 'Sheet1')
sheet2 = pd.read_excel(df, 'Sheet2')
```

Here, `sheet1` and `sheet2` are the dataframes for respective sheets.

You want to check whether, for a particular column values of sheet1 are present in the same column of sheet2.

Consider below example:

```
In [1898]: sheet1                                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[1898]: 
   id_col1 id_col2  name  age  sex
0      101      1M   NaN   21  NaN
1      101      3M   NaN   21    M
2      102      1M  Mark   25  NaN

In [1899]: sheet2                                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[1899]: 
   id_col1 id_col2   name   age   sex
0      101      1M  Steve   NaN     M
1      101      2M    NaN   NaN     M
2      101      3M  Steve  25.0  None
3      102      1M    Ria  25.0     M
4      102      2M   Anie  22.0     F
```

From above dataframes, columns `id_col1` are present in both sheet1 and sheet2.

So, let's check if all values of `id_col1` from sheet1 are present in `id_col1` of sheet2.

```
In [1900]: sheet1['id_col1'].isin(sheet2['id_col1'])                                                                                                                                                        
Out[1900]: 
0    True
1    True
2    True
Name: id_col1, dtype: bool
```

You can have a `for` loop and do the same for all columns:

```
In [1902]: for col in sheet1.columns.tolist(): 
      ...:     print(sheet1[col].isin(sheet2[col])) 
      ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                  
0    True
1    True
2    True
Name: id_col1, dtype: bool
0    True
1    True
2    True
Name: id_col2, dtype: bool
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: name, dtype: bool
0    False
1    False
2     True
Name: age, dtype: bool
0    False
1     True
2    False
Name: sex, dtype: bool
```